# The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: oracle, .net-4.0, odac, .net-client-profile, target-framework

I have created a new Console Application project with Visual Studio 2010 (I tried with VS 2012 and the problem is the same).
The using are:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

In the Main method I wrote this code:

```
   var oracleInstance = OracleClientFactory.Instance;
        using (DbConnection conn = oracleInstance.CreateConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString =
                "Data Source=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;";
            conn.Open();

            var command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 where rownum = 1";

            DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Column number {0}: {1}", i, reader[i]);
                }
            }
}
```

The target framework is .NET 4.0 . I referenced Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.3.0 (.NET 4).

The problem is: **if I target .NET 4.0, the compilation doesn't work** and it says *The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
**If I target .NET 4.0 Client Profile, it works fine.** 
The fact is that **I need to target .NET 4.0 framework, NOT .NET 4.0 Client Profile**!!

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: have you tried setting the cpu platform to x86?